# Validate Date in Go Template

Tags: go, go-templates

I am trying to ensure I have a valid date in my template file and if so populate a div, otherwise leave it blank. The data type is mysql.NullTime.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
{{ if .StartDate ne nil }}
   <div class="box date-row" id="startdate-{{ .DepartureTimeID }}">{{ .StartDate.Format "2006-01-02" }}</div>
{{ else }}
   <div class="box date-row" id="startdate-{{ .DepartureTimeID }}"></div>
{{ end }}
```

That does seem to work, how can I test for a non-null date?

Comment: Post complete struct or other details. Is `StartDate` a pointer?

Comment: No I have a structure in go which .StartDate is a member of. As mentioned it is of type "mysql.NullTime"

Comment: Make it a pointer and do not assign value if there is none to assign. You can do nil check on pointers. Otherwise it will be have default initialization values. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a mandatory value, you should validate it *before* you render the template.

However, if it is optional and/or you are writing a template driven application, you have at least two options to achieve what you want.

### Using zero values only

Put zero values to good use: for `time.Time` that is [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). So, assuming you can not have a `StartDate` in the past, you can compare wether your StartDate is after epoch.

```golang
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "os"
    "time"
)

// Note the call to the `After` function of the date.
const templateText = `
{{ if .Data.StartDate.After .Epoch }}
   <div class="box date-row" id="startdate-{{ .Data.DepartureTimeID }}">{{ .Data.StartDate.Format "2006-01-02" }}</div>
{{ else }}
   <div class="box date-row" id="startdate-{{ .Data.DepartureTimeID }}">No date</div>
{{ end }}
`

func main() {

     // shortcut for the sake of brevity.
    tmpl := template.Must(template.New("titleTest").Parse(templateText))

    // Create an anonymous wrapper struct for your data and the additional
    // time value you need to compare against
    tcx := struct {

        // This of course may be of the type you actually use.
        Data struct {
            StartDate       time.Time
            DepartureTimeID int
        }
        Epoch time.Time
    }{
        Data: struct {
            StartDate       time.Time
            DepartureTimeID int
        }{time.Now(), 1},
        Epoch: time.Time{},
    }

    tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, tcx)
}
```

<kbd>[**Run on playground**](https://play.golang.org/p/13cYj_Uylj8)</kbd>

### Using a custom function

This is pretty much self explanatory: simply define a custom function that validates your date. In this example, I have checked against the zero value again. However, you can get as granular as you wish, of course:

```golang
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "os"
    "log"
    "time"
)

const templateText = `
{{ if afterEpoch .StartDate }}
   <div class="box date-row" id="startdate-{{ .DepartureTimeID }}">{{ .StartDate.Format "2006-01-02" }}</div>
{{ else }}
   <div class="box date-row" id="startdate-{{ .DepartureTimeID }}"></div>
{{ end }}
`

func AfterEpoch(t time.Time) bool {
    return t.After(time.Time{})
}

type yourData struct {
    DepartureTimeID int
    StartDate       time.Time
}

func main() {
    funcMap := template.FuncMap{
        "afterEpoch": AfterEpoch,
    }

    tmpl := template.Must(template.New("fmap").Funcs(funcMap).Parse(templateText))

    log.Println("First run")
    tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, yourData{1, time.Now()})


    log.Println("Second run")
    tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, yourData{DepartureTimeID:1})
}
```

**Edit**:

Of course, you can also use the pipe notation for the second solution, which is by for more readable, imho: `{{ if .StartDate | afterEpoch }}`

<kbd>[**Run on playground**](https://play.golang.org/p/HuaI2UDJZbl)</kbd>

Comment: Great thanks a lot, I added an "epoch" member to my structure who's value gets intialized to time.Time{} but never set so I can compare against that. Good solution, never thought of that.

Comment: @mgrenier I would not add it to your general data structure. Using an anonymous struct as template context is fine and it does not polute your model.